# Example of polynomial from Wiener process which is martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

It is quite well-known that it is possible to construct polynomial of any power that will be a martingale. For example, for square and cube examples are $W^2_t-t$ and $W^3_t-3tW_t$. Can anyone give me an example for degree four?

Comment: This is related to Hermite polynomials. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214054/relation-between-hermite-polynomials-and-brownian-motion-on-martingale-property