# $_(,_)$ is a martingale

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, hermite-polynomials

Please explain how to prove that $_(,_)$ is a martingale.

H_n(x,y)=∂^n/∂α^n exp(αx−1/2(α^2)y) at α=0.

Xαt=exp(αWt−1/2(α^2)t)=∑n=0∞α^n/n! Hn(Wt,t).

I found a lot of literature just claiming this, but nobody proves it anywhere.

Comment: May help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214054/relation-between-hermite-polynomials-and-brownian-motion-on-martingale-property

Comment: Unless you *define* $H_n(t,x)$, you could as well ask for the age of the captain (sorry for being blunt).