# Compute the $n$th stochastic integral of Brownian motions

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, hermite-polynomials

> Show that the following equivalence of the $n$th stochastic integral
>
> $$n!\int\dots\int_{0\leq s_1\dots\leq s_n\leq t}dW_{s_1}\dots dW_{s_n}=t^{n/2}H_n \left(\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} \right)$$
>
> where $H_n$ is the Hermite polynomial.

We know that the Hermite polynomial is:

$$H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}),$$ moreover we have the recursive relation $$H_{n+1}(x)=2xH_{n}(x)-H_{n}'(x).$$

If we consider the case $n=2$ the stochastic integral:

$$\begin{align*} 2\int_{0}^{s_1}\int_{s_1}^tdW_{u} \, dW_{s_2}  &=2\int_{0}^{s_1}\left(\int_{s_1}^tdW_{u} \right)dW_{s_2} \\& =2\int_{0}^{s_1}(W_t-W_{s_1})\, dW_{s_2} \\ & =2 \left(\int_{0}^{s_1}W_t \, dW_{s_2}-\int_{0}^{s_1}W_{s_1} \, dW_{s_2} \right) \\ &=2 \left(\int_{0}^{s_1}W_t \, dW_{s_2}-\int_{0}^{s_1}W_{s_1} \, dW_{s_2} \right) \end{align*}$$

where we have $\int_{0}^{s_1}W_{s_1}dW_{s_2}=\frac{W_{s_1}-s_1}{2}$. On the other hand, we have:

$$H_2 \left(\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} \right)=4\frac{W_t^2}{t}-2 \quad \implies \quad  tH_2 \left(\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{t}} \right)=2(W_t^2-t)$$

How can I generalise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set

$$F_n(t,x) := \frac{(-t)^n}{n!} \exp \left( \frac{x^2}{2t} \right) \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2t} \right),$$

then a straight-forward application of the chain rule shows that

$$F_n(t,x) = \frac{1}{n!} t^{n/2} H_n \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} \right),$$

and therefore the assertion is equivalent to

$$\int \ldots \int_{0 \leq s_1 \leq \ldots \leq s_n \leq t} dW_{s_1} \ldots \, dW_{s_n} = F_n(t,W_t). \tag{1}$$

An application of Itô's formula and elementary (but somewhat messy) computations show that

$$dF_{n+1}(t,W_t) = F_n(t,W_t) \, dW_t \tag{2},$$

see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/981606/36150) for details, and then $(1)$ follows by a simple induction. (Mind that the notation which is used in the linked answer is different from the notation in the present question/answer!)

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not see how to get rid of the multiple integral. Could you please reformulate how the induction work to show (1)?

Comment: @FunnyBuzer Where exactly are you stuck...? Unless I miss something, it's really just a matter of writing down everything... first you will have to note that $$\iint_{0 \leq s_1 \leq \ldots \leq s_{n+1} \leq t} dW_{s_1} \ldots dW_{s_{n+1}} = \int_0^t \iint_{0 \leq s_1 \leq \ldots \leq s_n \leq s_{n+1}} \, dW_{s_1} \ldots dW_{s_n} \, dW_{s_{n+1}}$$ and then you can use directly the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I'm stuck exactly on the point where I need to compute this multiple integral. In my question, I tried to look at the 2-dim case, i.e. I will have $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s_1}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}dW_{s_1}dW_{s_2}$

Comment: @FunnyBuzer So why are you stuck there? Now you can use the result for $n=2$ for the inner two integrals.

Comment: ok, I wanted to confirm my computation above is correct.